# Image Overlay using the Street View Image API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view, google-maps-static-api

I am wondering if i am allowed to add an image overlay to a static Google Street View image.
The idea behind this question is adding a person/object to the street view image in an android application (and displaying it) without further processing of the outcome.

Would this violate "10.1.3 a)" of the Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service?
I am not really sure about that, because "(i) creating server-side modification of map tiles" is listed as a forbidden example, but I only want to do add a client-based overlay without modifying the Street View Image as itself.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Did you read this section? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewOverlays

It seems that the Street View API supports overlays.

Answer (score -1):

If you read the link from Vitor, it says that:

> "Currently, the types of overlays which are supported on Street View
>   panoramas are limited to Markers, InfoWindows and custom OverlayViews.
>   "

So unless you implement your own custom overlayview, image overlays (like a ground overlay) aren't supported

Comment: errrr: http://projects.teammaps.com/projects/streetviewoverlay/streetviewoverlay.htm

Comment: that's a custom overlayview-

Comment: I don't disagree, however, it used an overloaded marker with a gif to do what the poster asked without a violation of the terms of service.